# Fitting 8 column layout in 12-grid bootstrap layout?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Okay, so I was trying to recreate this page using Bootstrap, but I got stuck at this part right here.
[image]

My 2 questions are:

1. Which html element should be used for these lines?
2. How do I split the 12-column layout into 8 equal pieces?

Code sample:

```
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 3%; ">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class='form-control' placeholder="First Name">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class='form-control' placeholder="Last Name">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class='form-control' placeholder="Display name">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class='form-control' placeholder="Email Address">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="password" class='form-control' placeholder="Password">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="password" class='form-control' placeholder="Confirm Password">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary">I Agree</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-9">
                    <p>
                        By clicking <span class="label label-primary">Register</span> you agree to the <a href=#>Terms and Conditions</a> set out by this site, including our Cookie Use
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">

            </div>

            <div class="row" style="">
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" style="font-weight: bold;">Register</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <button class="btn btn-success btn-block" style="font-weight: bold; ">Sign In</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The other way is to split the row into two, and every half on four, like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-3></div>
            <div class="col-xs-3></div>
            <div class="col-xs-3></div>
            <div class="col-xs-3></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-3></div>
            <div class="col-xs-3></div>
            <div class="col-xs-3></div>
            <div class="col-xs-3></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So you will have eight equal sections and will save the wrapper.

Which html element should be used for these lines - here you can try with div, span, even hr. Just try. :)

Comment: Glad to help you! :)

Comment: The second row should be `<div class="col-xs-6">`

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-2></div>
  <div class="col-xs-8">{YOUR COLORS HERE}</div>
  <div class="col-xs-2></div>
</div>
```

You can use the colors as an image or a set of divs wrapped in in a container to have them all float together on the same line always.

```
 <div style="position:relative;display:block;width:100%;height:16px">
  <div style="position:relative;display:inline-block;width:12.5%;background-color:red"></div>
  <div style="position:relative;display:inline-block;width:12.5%;background-color:blue"></div>
  <div style="position:relative;display:inline-block;width:12.5%;background-color:green"></div>
  <div style="position:relative;display:inline-block;width:12.5%;background-color:orange"></div>
  <div style="position:relative;display:inline-block;width:12.5%;background-color:teal"></div>
  <div style="position:relative;display:inline-block;width:12.5%;background-color:cyan"></div>
  <div style="position:relative;display:inline-block;width:12.5%;background-color:purple"></div>
  <div style="position:relative;display:inline-block;width:12.5%;background-color:black"></div>
 </div>
```

This will give you equal padding on both sides of your colorful row :) hope this works for you. Also you can do the same for all your rows in order to have everything aligned like the image, just a bit padded and still centered.
Or split the row into 2 (6) and then each into 4 (3)

Comment: You're welcome, keep in mind there are several ways to implement this.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="row col-xs-3">
        <div class="col-xs-6"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-6"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row col-xs-3">
        <div class="col-xs-6"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-6"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row col-xs-3">
        <div class="col-xs-6"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-6"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row col-xs-3">
        <div class="col-xs-6"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-6"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row col-xs-3">
        <div class="col-xs-6"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-6"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

or this

```
<style>
.colorbar{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: -2px;
    width: 12.5%;
    height: 10px;
}
/*add some color*/
</style>
<div class="row">
    <span class="colorbar"></span>
    <span class="colorbar"></span>
    <span class="colorbar"></span>
    <span class="colorbar"></span>
    <span class="colorbar"></span>
    <span class="colorbar"></span>
    <span class="colorbar"></span>
    <span class="colorbar"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The most easy method that I used for these style is using `HTML5 Canvas` .
So I write this code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <style type="text/css">

        #myCanvas {
            width: 500px;
        }

    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="20" >Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>

    <script>
        var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var line1 = c.getContext("2d");
        line1.beginPath();
        line1.moveTo(0,0);
        line1.lineTo(100,0);
        line1.lineWidth = 20;
        line1.strokeStyle = "#6FCCAC";
        line1.stroke();

        var line2 = c.getContext("2d");
        line2.beginPath();
        line2.moveTo(100,0);
        line2.lineTo(200,0);
        line2.lineWidth = 20;
        line2.strokeStyle = "#9830B5";
        line2.stroke();

        var line3 = c.getContext("2d");
        line3.beginPath();
        line3.moveTo(200,0);
        line3.lineTo(300,0);
        line3.lineWidth = 20;
        line3.strokeStyle = "#B55C59";
        line3.stroke();

        var line4 = c.getContext("2d");
        line4.beginPath();
        line4.moveTo(300,0);
        line4.lineTo(400,0);
        line4.lineWidth = 20;
        line4.strokeStyle = "#6A8ED2";
        line4.stroke();

        var line5 = c.getContext("2d");
        line5.beginPath();
        line5.moveTo(400,0);
        line5.lineTo(500,0);
        line5.lineWidth = 20;
        line5.strokeStyle = "#C2C153";
        line5.stroke();

        var line6 = c.getContext("2d");
        line6.beginPath();
        line6.moveTo(500,0);
        line6.lineTo(600,0);
        line6.lineWidth = 20;
        line6.strokeStyle = "#00C2AE";
        line6.stroke();

        var line7 = c.getContext("2d");
        line7.beginPath();
        line7.moveTo(600,0);
        line7.lineTo(700,0);
        line7.lineWidth = 20;
        line7.strokeStyle = "#79C257";
        line7.stroke();

        var line8 = c.getContext("2d");
        line8.beginPath();
        line8.moveTo(700,0);
        line8.lineTo(800,0);
        line8.lineWidth = 20;
        line8.strokeStyle = "#D5DB22";
        line8.stroke();
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

If you want to learn how to use `Canvas` I always offer these sites :

- [html5canvastutorials](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/)
- [W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp)
- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API)

  But for explaining my code ... You see a `style` tag in `head` tags . As you should get it that the code identify the canvas real `width` . And when I say real width that mean it's different from the `width` that you see in the canvas tag . The `width` and `height` that we use in canvas tag is just to have a work area to set points of a graph like a fill or a stroke . And every hexadecimal codes is the lines color .
  Hope It Will Be Helpful ...